# Does having a full-stop make any difference in the field of firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the code. It reads the value of "**1@gmail**" but gives **null** for "**1@gmail.com**". Can anyone explain why is it so?

```
for(DocumentSnapshot document:task.getResult()){
                            String status = document.getString("1@gmail");
                            String status2 = document.getString("1@gmail.com");
                            Log.v(TAG, "index=" + status);
                            Log.v(TAG, "index=" + status2);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `.` is a special character with Firestore documents.  First, see the documentation on Firestore "[Constraints on field paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields)":

> Must separate field names with a single period (.)

The field path you've given with "1@gmail.com" contains a `.`, which is interpreted as a field path separator.  What it's doing is looking for an object field in the document called `1@gmail`, then trying to access that object's `com` field.  Obviously, that's not going to be found here, and it returns null.

If you want to access a field name with a `.` in it, you'll have to wrap that into a [FieldPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath) object:

```
Object o = document.get(FieldPath.of("1@gmail.com"));
String status2 = (String) o;
```

Comment: Ohh... didn't know that. This helps. Thanks. Again Doug Stevenson:D

Comment: It is showing Error: getString
(java.lang.String)
in DocumentSnapshot cannot be applied
to
(com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldPath)

Comment: I edited my answer.  FieldPath is only valid with get(), which returns an Object.  You have to check/cast the resulting to the expected type, which will be Boolean if the value is a boolean.